# Nativescript - Add to favorites/featured

Tags: nativescript

I´m in that point on my app where i need to **give the user the ability to save to favorites**. To be more specific, let´s say that he´s seeing a list-view and then presses one of the listitems which takes him to the detail of that item...here i have a star icon that when pressed it should save that item and then if he navigates to the favorites page, he will see another listview with all of the favorites.

but i´m stuck on how to accomplish this, the only thing that comes to my mind is the **application settings**...**it should be a dynamic array that always exists and then keeps adding or deleting objects(favorites)**.

Any thougts on this? can anyone suggest me an approach? maybe a better one?

Regards

Comment: There are different ways for storing persistent data in your application. The easiest is application settings and other options are file-system / nativescript-localstorage / sqlite etc., The [docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-framework-modules/application-settings) covers most for you, so may I know where exactly you are facing issue?

Comment: Hey Manoj, thanks for answering..yes i know the docs have(mor or less) all explain...my issuewas which option to take...but i think i´m going with the file system module...it´s a dynamic array, so everytime the user "adds to favorites" i will have to pull the file from file system, and then add it again to the system and i was just wondering if there was any other(better) way of doind this. regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the `nativescript-localstorage` plugin which internally uses file system only and takes care of reading / updating JSON file as needed.

Comment: Thanks for your help Manoj